# Why we use cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) or rgb2gray(img) in skimage

Tags: opencv, rgb, normalization, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract features using GLCM. I have seen an online code where the author is doing a series of steps for preprocessing before applying GLCM.

1. Converting image to grayscale by using img_gray=rgbgray(image) and then normalizing it using img_rescaled=(img_gray -np.min(img_resized))/(np.max(img_resized)-np.min(img_resized))#min-max normalization
   .
2. But in the second step he is again converting images using img= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) and normalizing it again using  img_rescaled = (img - np.min(img)) / (np.max(img) - np.min(img))

I don't understand why he is again converting the image into grayscale and normalizing it in 2nd step. Can anyone help me in that.

Thank You in advance

Comment: You have omitted the link to the code you are discussing.

Comment: Hi Mark here it is https://github.com/abzargar/COVID-Classifier. If you see process_images.py here the author is converting images into grayscale as well as doing rescaling and now if you see extract. features file then use the for loop professor is doing the same again like converting images into grayscale and normalizing it